# How can I deploy a new cloudfront s3 version without a small period of unavailability?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I am utilizing AWS cloudfront with an S3 origin.  I'm using a webpack plugin to cache-bust using [chunked hash file names](https://webpack.github.io/docs/long-term-caching.html) for all of my static files excluding index.html, which I will simply invalidate using the cloudfront feature upon each new release.

I plan on using a jenkins build to run `aws s3 sync ./dist s3://BUCKET-NAME/dist 
 --recursive --delete` which will swap out the new chunked files as necessary.  Then I will overwrite the `index.html` file to use the new chunked reference.  During the few seconds (max) it takes to swap out the old files for new, it is possible that a user will make a request to the website from a region in which cloudfront has not cached the resources, at which point they'll be unavailable because I have just deleted them.

I could not find any information about avoiding this edge case.

Comment: What about two consecutive syncs, with only the second one using `--delete`?  Wouldn't that solve the issue entirely?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it can happen that a person near a different edge location experience the missing files. To solve this, you need to change the approach of doing new deployments since cache busting and time is unpredictable at request-response level. One commonly used pattern is to keep different directories(paths) for each new deployment in S3 as follows.

```
For release v1.0
/dist/v1.0/js/*
/dist/v1.0/css/*
/dist/index.html <- index.html for v1.0 release which has reference for js & css in /dist/v1.0 path

For release v1.1
/dist/v1.1/js/*
/dist/v1.1/css/*
/dist/index.html <- index.html for v1.1 release which has reference for js & css in /dist/v1.1 path
```

After each deployment, a user will receive either the old version(v1.0) or new version(v1.1) of the index.html, which will still working during the transition period until the edge cache is busted.

You can automate the versioning with Jenkins either incrementing the version or using [parameterize build plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Build?focusedCommentId=37323537).

This will also be useful to do immutable deployments, where in a case of a critical issue, you can rollback to the previous deployments. Apart from that you can configure S3 lifecycle management rules to archive the older versions.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I solved that problem.

Just deleting flat will not solve the issue.
Since you have chunked hash file names I assume you have only index.html that is not hashed filename.

Collect all old files which need to be deleted

```
aws s3 ls s3://bucket
```

Deploy all files from your new build.

```
aws s3 cp ./dist s3://bucket
```

Remove old files now either with mv or delete

```
aws s3 rm files you collected before except index.html
```

Your new site will be served with the new app now.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I don't think this would work because it's possible you'd end up removing a chunked hash filename that has not changed since the last deployment in step 3

Comment: I have not seen a build that retains old chunked filename on a new build. Everytime you deploy, all of the files will have new names. Doing a different hash will make the build process complex or you need to maintain versions.

Answer (score 1):

A library called [Stout](https://github.com/cloudflare/Stout) can do this all for you automatically. It's a major time saver. I have no association with them, I just really like it.

A few benefits:

- Can help you **create** new buckets if you want it to
- **Versions** your script and style files during each deploy to ensure your pages don't use an inconsistent set of files during or after a deploy
- Supports **rollback** to any previous version
- Properly handles **caching headers** such as TTL
- **Compresses files** for faster delivery

Usage:

```
stout deploy --bucket my-bucket-name --root path/to/website
```